# Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue during Neo4jConnection

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, linq, neo4jclient

I've set up my neo4j connection but is not working but rather throwing the error:

> Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue.

This is Neo4j ninject module file:

```
public class Neo4jModule : NinjectModule
{
    /// <summary>Loads the module into the kernel.</summary>
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IGraphClient>().ToMethod(InitNeo4JClient).InSingletonScope();
    }

    private static IGraphClient InitNeo4JClient(IContext context)
    {
        var neo4JUri = new Uri("http://www.example.com");
        var graphClient = new GraphClient(neo4JUri, "username", "password");
        graphClient.Connect();

        return graphClient;
    }
}
```

This is my RegisterServices method for my Ninject.Web.Common file:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Load<Neo4jModule>();
    }
```

I don't understand why i am getting this error. This exception is caught at:

```
graphClient.Connect();
```

I also debugged my application and realised that the graphclient object upon creation comes with many errors. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole wasn't faulty. The error came from my uri to the GraphClient object. For example http://localhost:7474/ is wrong url.The correct and accepted url is http://localhost:7474/db/data.

```
var neo4JUri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/db/data");
```

That's all there is the connection working.